# when logouting a user session::flush() laravels wont work

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I am using laravel to build a site that has a sign in authentication and when a user logs out, they can still click the back button for the browser and puff.. they are back in. so here is my code i am using session::flush to delete the session but it wont work.

this is my code

public function signout()
    {

```
    Session::flush();
    Auth::logout(); 
    return Redirect::action('ViewController@signin');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Often when a user hits 'back' on their browser, their browser simply shows them a cached version of the page. They shouldn't be able to actually interact with the page (ie submit a form) or do anything that requires a new request to the server without the server responding that they are logged out.

Answer (score 0):

Using filter can be a solution for this problem. (I didn't find any other solution yet) First, add this code in filters.php :

```
Route::filter('no-cache',function($route, $request, $response){

    $response->header("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store, must-revalidate");
    $response->header("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    $response->header("Expires"," Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

});
```

Then attach this filter to routes or controllers. I attached it into construct function of controller like this:

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf',array('on' => 'post'));
        $this->afterFilter("no-cache", ["only"=>"getDashboard"]);
    }
```